# Functions ... is deprecated

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Установил php, phpmyadmin и mysqsl.
При подключении к БД через phpmyadmin вылезает куча сообщений

> Deprecation Notice in .\libraries\phpseclib\Crypt\Base.php#1592
>    Function mcrypt_list_algorithms() is deprecated "

Почему они устарели? вроде последняя версия...
Как устранить?

Comment: .......... почему устарел `mcrypt_list_algorithms`? потому что есть уязвимости и есть более надежные функции, логично же......... устарел с PHP 7.1

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский,  Ну это понятно. интересно почему они устарели в последней версии (phpMyAdmin-4.6.5.2). Вроде популярная тузла. Полагаю обновляется часто... И совсем не понятно как запретить вывод этих сообщение, а то они изрядно бесят.

Comment: `почему они устарели в последней версии` - потому что phpmyadmin юзает самую новую версию PHP? очевидно же))) ........а вообще, ну что-то они упустили.......не беда...... эту ошибку в 4.6.6 пофиксили.... так что у вас не новая версия ;-)

Comment: .......... а самый топорный вариант с этой версией (для вас он не должен быть критическим)  — это отключить предупреждения вида `Notice`.... ну или те которые `E_DEPRECATED`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский,  спасибо!

Comment: Проверил на сайте, последний релиз  2016-12-05: phpMyAdmin 4.6.5.2 is released. Если такое в релизе, то на бета версию даже смотреть не хочу :)

Comment: моё мнение: забейте вы на этот phpmyadmin. скачайте нормальную программу для работы с БД. Минимум - вам будут предоставлены ресурсы компьютера для выполнения запросов и прочего, а не бедного браузера. А также плюшки с автокомплитами, профайлерами и прочими вещами.

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, уже поставил ВоркБенч

Comment: @АлексейШиманский более надежная функция вывода списка алгоритмов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сама библиотека [`libmcrypt`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/files/Libmcrypt/) заброшена в 2007 году.

В прошлом году разработчики PHP приняли [предложение объявить расширение](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mcrypt-viking-funeral) `mcrypt` устаревшим в связи с тем, что базовая библиотека имеет ошибки и не поддерживается, а так же из-за довольно плохо спроектированного набора функций, способствующего появлению ошибок в криптографии. Когда-нибудь позже расширение будет выселено в PECL пакет и поддерживаться уже не будет.

Касательно именно вашего phpmyadmin - последний релиз 4.6.5.2 вышел 5 декабря, ошибку [заметили и исправили только 10 декабря](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12800). Банально сообщество phpmyadmin прохлопало подготовку release notes вышедшего 1 декабря PHP 7.1 и никто даже не протестировал совместимость ни во время альфа и бета тестов, ни релиз кандидаты.

Обратите внимание на комментарий коммитера, кстати:

> There will be more problems in PHP 7.1 and 4.6 right now.

Видимо, известны ещё другие проблемы работы phpmyadmin 4.6 под PHP 7.1.

Comment: Познавательно. Спасибо за ответ!